# Android app does not open in samsung tab3

Tags: android, crashlytics

Playstore app is downloaded and installed in samsung galaxy tab 3. But when user tries to open it, blank white screen is shown before exiting and without any crash. There is no way of knowing whether its a code error or service error without any crashes or error reports from user. Currently using fabric for reporting crashes. How to troubleshoot such errors or to know the root issue.

Comment: You have to get a crash log.  Either work with the user to get them to test it, or buy a tab 3 and test it yourself.  But from something this generic we can't tell you what it is.

Comment: @Abhishek Read the post again. "Currently using Fabric"

Comment: try opening the app with usb debugging on and remove the cable as soon as get a crash to see traces in `logcat` with Android Studio. This has worked for me few times.

Answer (score 0):

Ask user a favor to do step 1-8 and to send log file to you:

1. Assume Developer Options is on. Connect the Samsung device to the PC using USB, it will pop up a message Connected as a media device, click on the message, on the settings page select Connected as Media device (MTP).
   After this change, you should be able to see the samsung device on your PC.
2. Find out the location of ...\android\android-sdk\platform-tools on the PC.
3. Open CMD window, type in the command
   `cd ...\android\android-sdk\platform-tools` 
   please replace ...to the real path of ...\android\android-sdk\platform-tools in your environment
4. Run the command below 
   `adb devices`  and
   `adb shell`
5. Typing in the command below
   `logcat -v time -f /sdcard/test1.log`
   /sdcard/test1.log it's suggested to plugin SD card on the device, and specify the path with real sdcard path.
6. Reproduce the issue
7. Once the issue replicated, press Ctrl + C to stop capturing the log, and press Ctrl +D to exit adb shell mode
8. Run command below to pull logs from device to PC:
   `adb pull /sdcard/test1.log` 
   The log file will be shown under folder platform-tools

Comment: How does this answer the question about troubleshooting errors?